# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' at openEdx exchange_token api

Tags: django, azure-active-directory, openedx

I was working on the azure ad login for openEdx mobile app and as mentioned in the title,  I got the NoneType response at token_exchange endpoint from azure ad.

Azure login have no problem authentication the user from the website login but login from the mobile got 'Service unavailable response' due to the following error log on the server.

I suspect the configuration issue but as far as I checked, i only need to set 'SOCIAL_AUTH_OAUTH_SECRETS' from lms.auth.json and 'THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_BACKENDS' and 'ENABLE_THIRD_PARTY_AUTH' from lms.env.json.

Please let me know if I miss something out. Thanks in advance

```
Apr  1 12:38:45 edxapp [service_variant=lms][django.request][env:sandbox] ERROR [edxapp  24509] [exception.py:135] - Internal Server Error: /oauth2/exchange_access_token/azuread-oauth2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 185, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/oauth_dispatch/views.py", line 57, in dispatch
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/auth_exchange/views.py", line 44, in dispatch
    return super(AccessTokenExchangeBase, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/auth_exchange/views.py", line 57, in post
    if not form.is_valid():
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 385, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/provider/forms.py", line 63, in _clean_form
    super(OAuthForm, self)._clean_form()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 412, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/auth_exchange/forms.py", line 95, in clean
    user = backend.do_auth(access_token, allow_inactive_user=True)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 252, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 410, in do_auth
    data = self.user_data(access_token, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/azuread.py", line 80, in user_data
    id_token = response.get('id_token')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Do you get it to work? I am facing the same issue, on the website it works fine but on mobile it throws this error

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I made it work. You need to implement this token exchange method by yourself. It wasn't implemented inside. :(